# Problems when reading from a FILE and use strtok function

Tags: c++

I have writen a code in C++ that must read information from a txt file and when it finds a "|" character it must jump to a new line. Its something quite easy but Im having problems when executing and Ive been trying to find the problem for hours and I havent suceed.  :( I attached the code.

Thaaaanks in advance for your help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string ruta_base( "C:\\a\\" );
   char * pch;

   ifstream myReadFile;
   const string rutaFichero=ruta_base.append("text.txt");
   myReadFile.open(rutaFichero.c_str());

   char* temp;
   if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
      while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
         myReadFile.read(temp,1);

         pch = strtok(temp,"|");
         while (pch != NULL)
         {
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, "|");
         }
      }
   }
   myReadFile.close();

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? Please provide  a sample input file content and the output you get.

Comment: for example, my "text.txt" file would contain "1|Peter|Professor" and the output would be: 
    1 
    Peter 
    Professor 

(every different element after "|" in a new line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using uninitialized pointer `temp` in `read` function. Trying to write to this memory location will invoke undefined behavior. Dont create a `temp` as a pointer. Instead you can do `char temp;` and pass the address of temp i.e. `&temp` to the `read` function. Then you need not use `strtok`, you can simply compare the character read to `|`

Comment: I have done the changes in temp, but I am still having problems. It compiles perfectly, but I have problems when executing it. 

In the end it appears on screen strange characters and 
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack aroun the variable "temp" was corrupted. What does this mean???

Comment: @pitbull: with very high probability, this means that you tried to `read` more than one `char` in the single `char temp;`. The other characters spill over.